# How can I create a jquery event based on the value of a check box?

Tags: jquery

Basically I have a list of checkboxes that I need to hide by default and show them if the main checkbox is visible

```
<div class="parent"> 
    <input type="checkbox" class="subjectChk"> 
    <div class="childCont">
        <input type="checkbox" class="subjGradeChk hidden">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="parent"> 
    <input type="checkbox" class="subjectChk"> 
    <div class="childCont">
        <input type="checkbox" class="subjGradeChk hidden">
    </div>
</div>
```

The goal is to say if `subjectChk` value is checked then removeClass `hidden` from `subjGradeChk`

I have tried doing something like this

```
$('.subjGradeChk').on('click',function(){ 
if(this.checked){ 
$(.subjGradeChk).removeClass('hidden'); } });
```

but I want it to just affect each instance based on the parent

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes something like this
$('.subjGradeChk').on('click',function(){
    if(this.checked){
        $(.subjGradeChk).removeClass('hidden');
    }
});
the only problem is that it affects all subjGradeChk inputs... I wanted it based on one parent..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest, at the simplest:

```
// binds the 'change' event-handler to all elements with that class:
$('.subjectChk').change(function(){
    /* selects the closest '.parent' element from the changed element,
       finds the '.subjGradeChk' element(s) within that parent,
       if the changed element is 'checked' we use the removeClass() method,
       otherwise the addClass() method to change the '.hidden' class: */
    $(this).closest('.parent').find('.subjGradeChk')[this.checked ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass']('hidden');
// we trigger the 'change' event:
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6jB69/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Comment: I'm glad to have helped! :D

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
if($('.subjectChk').attr('checked')){
 $('.subjectChk').next().show();` 
}else{
 $('.subjectChk').next().hide();
```

}`

Comment: You should be using `prop()` for the `checked` property (not `attr()`). Also, I'm not sure that the OP wants to hide, or show, the *next* (`div` element, or the child checkbox of that element).

Answer (score 0):

The event would go something like this:

```
$('.subjGradeChk').on('click',function(){
    if(this.checked){
        $(this).removeClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

`this.checked` is vanilla JS, but for situations like this vanilla JS works wonderfully. And its a crapload faster. :D